# Generic generic extension method (sic!)

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, extension-methods

Is it possible to add an extension method to a generic class that is independent of that class' instance generic type?

I want to write a extension method for handling Nullable values. So far, the method looks like this:

```
public static object GetVerifiedValue(this Nullable<> obj)
{
    return obj.HasValue ? obj.Value : DBNull.Value;
}
```

But the compiler doesn't accept the `Nullable<>` type.

Is there any way I can do this?

Note: I'm using C# 3.0, .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make it a generic method:

```
public static object GetVerifiedValue<T>(this Nullable<T> obj)
    where T : struct
{
    return obj.HasValue ? obj.Value : DBNull.Value;
}
```

The calling code can use type inference when calling it:

```
int? x = 10;
object o = x.GetVerifiedValue();
```

EDIT: Another option is to use the boxing behaviour of nullable types:

```
public static object GetVerifiedValue(object obj)
{
    return obj ?? DBNull.Value;
}
```

Of course that doesn't verify that you're trying to pass in an expression of a nullable value type...

Comment: I don't want my code's user have to specify the type, since the method will return an `object`. Is it possible?

Comment: @Raphael: If the calling code already has the value in a strongly typed way, you can use type inference anyway, so the caller won't have to *explicitly* specify the type.

Comment: Note: the method requires a generic constraint, for T must be a Value Type. So don't forget adding `where T : struct` at the end of the method's signature.

Comment: ~Raphael: Thanks, have added the constraint.

Comment: Also, the second line of the calling code example should be `object o = x.GetVerifiedValue();`, since `x` is already a `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: @Raphael: Apologies, I hadn't noticed it was an extension method.